# Rxjava - How to retry an API call with different params while calling two APIs in parallel

Tags: android, rx-java2

I am making two API calls in the following way. If any of the two API calls fail, I would want to retry that API by changing certain params. How to achieve this?

```
Single.zip(API1.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()),
                API2.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()), Bifunction())).subscribe();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can use onErrorResumeNext to handle ur scenario here. For both the API calls add a onErrorResumeBlock which could be retrying the same api with diff params.
Like:

```
Single.zip(API1.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
     .onErrorResumeNext { throwable:Throwable ->
     return@onErrorResumeNext API1DIFF_PARAMS },
     API2.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
     .onErrorResumeNext { throwable:Throwable ->
     return@onErrorResumeNext API2DIFF_PARAMS }, Bifunction())).subscribe();
```

Downside is this will work only once. If your second API also fails then it will land in the error block of ur subscribe method

Comment: If I want to try with three or more times with different params, I can actually chain multiple onErrorResumeNext for one API, not just one. There is no downside. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Your onErrorResume would be needed to be nested, which can be difficult to read.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64115256/get-bitmap-from-url-with-other-api-calls-parallelly-using-glide-and-rxjava-in-an

Comment: The http 401 errors are not received in onErrorResumeNext. Is there a way to handle those in a similar scenario?

Comment: Not sure why. I might have to check that